# What does "lock up the concession" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "He was allowed to own..."?

"Invest when others fear. Fugger made two massive bets that secured his fortune. The first was to bankroll Archduke Sigmund of Tyrol when it looked like Venice was going to take over the duchy. The dukes’ usual bankers refused to finance him. Fugger came forward and offered everything he and his friends and family could pull together. The duke settled with Venice. In return for his backing, Fugger **locked up the concession** for the largest silver mine on earth."

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/7-money-making-lessons-from-the-richest-man-who-ever-lived-2017-05-02?link=TD_marketwatch_home_page.83461b39d1bfc251&utm_source=marketwatch_home_page.83461b39d1bfc251&utm_campaign=circular&utm_medium=MARKETWATCH

Comment: Have you looked up these two words?

Comment: Already. But I was not sure of its meaning.http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concession; http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lock-up

Comment: @haile It's using the third "big" definition under that link (right) _"a special right to property or land"_

Comment: He secured a monopoly on the concession.